# Accessing private dockerhub repository from aws codebuild

Tags: docker, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I created a codebuild project in aws. Now I want to build a docker container and push it in the ecr.

My buildspec.yaml in short looks like this:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . -f docker/aws.Dockerfile -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest --no-cache --build-arg NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
```

The problem is that I want to start from an image that is stored in my private dockerhub account. So my aws.Dockerfile starts with these lines:

```
FROM my-company/my-base:1.0
```

Is there any way to retrieve my image. I tried something like that in buildspec.yaml

```
  - DOCKER_LOGIN=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id DOCKER_HUB_LOGIN --query SecretString --output text | jq -r '.username + ":" + .password')
  - DOCKER_LOGIN_USER=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id DOCKER_HUB_LOGIN --query SecretString --output text | jq -r '.username')
  - echo $DOCKER_LOGIN | docker login --username $(echo $DOCKER_LOGIN_USER) --password-stdin
```

but I received the following error message
**Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: incorrect username or password. My username and password are correct.**

My guess is that I'm trying to log into ecr this way.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** It looks like there may be a mix up which repo your pulling from. You've logged into ECR, while your pulling from DockerHub's docker.io domain.

Consider a docker image name syntax: `<domain>/<repository name>:<tag>`

Similar to if you don't pass a tag, Docker will look for the `latest` tag, when you access a image from DockerHub, you can leave out the domain. This is because DockerHub's docker.io is default domain (ie `ubuntu:22.04` pulls from DockerHub's docker.io).

If you were to want to pull from ECR (or any other host, that is not DockerHub), you need to pass the full image domain with it, like: `public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/ubuntu:22.04` or a private ECR repo would be like `<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<availability_zone>.amazonaws.com/ubuntu:22.04`

With this knowledge of where you image is, you just need to login to the appropriate host, for DockerHub, it would be something like:

```
echo $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD | docker login --username foo --password-stdin`
```

You can store your DockerHub credentials in SSM's Parameter Store, to access in your CodeBuild yaml like this:

```yaml
env:
  parameter-store:
    DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD: /qa/DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Actually, I see this error after trying to log into dockerhub using docker login. What I tried step by step is: 1. Retrieve docker hub login from secrets manager 2. Log into docker hub with docker login 3. docker build with a file specifying to start from a dockerhub container. I see the error above on step 2. This happens before I'm trying to log into ecr. I even tried to move ecr logging in the postbuild section just before pushing to ecr but this doesn't help so far

Comment: @user732456 feel free to update the initial question with the dockerhub login example and the actually error txt from when the code build project is ran. I’m happy to take a peak.